# AngularJS $scope always convert member instances to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this simple code and Im used to organized my class, services etc.
now my problem is that why angular $scope always changes all member instances to object?

```
$scope.prepareCreateCustomer = function() {
    $scope.customer = new Customer({id:'',email:'',firstName:'',lastName:''});
    alert($scope.customer instanceof Customer); // this returns true!**
}

$scope.saveCustomer = function () {
    alert($scope.customer instanceof Customer); // this return false!**

    $scope.customer = customerService.createCustomer($scope.customer);
    if ($scope.customer.errorMsg) {
        alert($scope.customer.errorMsg);// this gets invoke as in service i have some logic**
    } else if ($scope.customer == null) {
        alert(Null);
    } else {
        alert($scope.customer.id + " " + $scope.customer.firstName + " " +$scope.customer.lastName);
    }
}
```

it puts me to confusion of what happen under beneath AngularJS and why instances get changes to its 
supertype? does this has something to do with AngularJS directives invoking the $scope?

My aim is to ensure that my argument as i save an object is to check if its the right instance but in my case it always return false as in Angular convert my Customer instance to an object.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
[image: Angular error]

Comment: For whatever you're trying to do here, you may want to look into the [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) docs

Comment: Are these for sure being run in the correct order? As in, is prepareCreateCustomer being called before saveCustomer?

Comment: Yes @ZackArgyle I am very certain that execution is in order. thanks

Comment: Must be something we can't see here. Here is a [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/mzok2kok/) that seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @ZackArgyle  but ` var dude = $scope.prepareDude();` you call this inside addDude() so your not preparing anything. I hope you dont mind. my scenario is that those methods are invoke using ng-click and i was thinking it has something todo with directives updating my instances against scope. this might be a bug for the angularJs but not confirmed.